# How to plot path for cyclic voltammetry

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, path

I'm trying to plot my cyclic voltammetry data, but since it is cyclic, every x value has more than 1 corresponding y value, and if the function geom_line gives me a filled in figure. I want it to be a line plotted in the order of the rows.

When I plot using geom_point, I get the right shape, but I still need lines, not points. I think I might not be using it right, but I've been trying with geom_path, but to no success.

```
(data=d6)
ggplot(d6[order(rownames(d6)),], aes(x, y),) + geom_path(aes(x=(e), y=value, colour=variable) )
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQE72.png) is the resulting plot.

Comment: Geom_line orders everything along x coordinates and then draws a line, while geom_path retains the order of the original dataframe and then draws a line. So when you reorder the rownames of `d6`, does the resulting data.frame reflect the order in which lines are to be drawn between points?

Comment: Hey Lucca! I've run across similar issues before. Is there any way you can post (using the `dput` command) enough of your data (say, 10 rows) so we can duplicate your problem and help solve it?